# iosでaudioタグを使い音量を制御したいです

Tags: javascript, monaca, html5

audioタグでvolumeを使用し音量を制御したいです。
WEBブラウザでは制御できるのですが、端末（ios）では制御できません。
音量を0.0～1.0の間で試しましたが、音量に違いがでない状態です。
開発環境はmonaca（https://ja.monaca.io/）です。
解決方法を教えていただけると助かります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
    // 音声の読み込み
    var audio = new Audio("se/sound.mp3");
    // 属性値を設定する
    audio.loop = 'true';
    //音声の再生
    audio.play();
    // 音声のボリューム制御
    audio.volume = 0.1;
```

Comment: Safari ドキュメント: [“Volume Control in JavaScript”](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW11) によると、 iOS 版の Safari では、 `audio.volume` は `1` 固定となるようですので、  `audio.volume` では実現できないところがスタート地点になりそうです。 Monaca の場合プラグインがあればいいんですかね...

Answer (score 2):

iOS6 以降であれば、`AudioContext`をはじめとする Web Audio API が使えそうです。

http://www.html5rocks.com/ja/tutorials/webaudio/intro/

この記事にちょうど音量調節のデモがあり、手元のiPadでも動作しました。